# Ragged Right in SSIS does not work properly

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, fixed-width

Hello: I have an SSIS package that imports a flat text file: the text file is a simple, fixed-width file that’s also CR/LF delimited. This means that: EACH record has a set of *fixed length **columns*** (the columns are defined using fixed lengths), but each record must also end with a CR/LF.

I’ve defined the package as follows:

### [image]

---

### [image]

[image]
**PROBLEM:**

Some records do not have all of the columns defined, and thus they are shorter. However, ALL records end with a CR/LF. First I tried to import it using “fixed width” file and the shorter records were misaligned because obviously it wasn’t fixed length. Now that I am using ragged right, I am still facing the same issue. Basically, for the shorter records, SSIS borrows from the next line to compensate for the thing. THE NEXT line, however, is just fine.

***POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS:*** 
1-  Ignore the rest of the columns that are not needed (basically ignore it): this works fine but is not elegant. I was hoping for a better solution. 
2-  USE the record type at the beginning to split BEFORE defining columns. This works fine also but I have over 500 fields, and the point of using the Flat File import is to be able to generate the columns automatically. 
3-  Use a script component: that seems like a difficult thing to do.

Comment: The expectation for the last screenshot is that it should be E and the subsequent columns should be blanked out?

Comment: @billinkc yes exactly!! Why isn't like that? Because after E we have CR/LF, so why isn't it going to the next record? It's acting like Fixed-width

Comment: @billinkc any luck??? Thanks!

Comment: Haven't had time to gin up a repro. To verify your tag though, this is a 2012+ SSIS package, yes?

Comment: @billinkc yes, that's correct: I use the SQL Server 2012 suite (including SSIS 2012)